# Nested React routes with dynamic route tags

Tags: reactjs, laravel, react-router

I'm going about routing slightly different with react router. I have a routes object with path, name and component:

```
const routes = [
    { path: '/', name: 'Home', Component: HomePage },
    { path: '/about', name: 'About', Component: AboutPage },
    { path: '/projects', name: 'Projects', Component: ProjectsPage },
    { path: '/blog' , name: 'Blog', Component: BlogPage },
    { path: `/blog/:id(\\d+)`, name: 'Post', Component: PostPage }
]
```

Then I'm mapping to create a  tag for each one:

```
{routes.map(({ path, Component }) => (
  <Route key={path} exact path={path}>
     {({ match }) => <Component data={dataObject} imagepath={imagePath} 
     in={match != null} />}
  </Route>
))}
```

So with the above implementation of `` `/blog/:id(\\d+)` ``, it won't work whereas I've tried this before in the usual set up without dynamically rendering a route and it works.

Any ideas how to cater for a nested route and still keep routing like this?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up creating a subRoutes object and mapping around that to create new routes just below the first map. It should render its own Route tag which is what I was going for. If anyone else has a different approach would be good to see it :)

```
const subRoutes = [
    { path: `/blog/:id(\\d+)`, name: 'Post', Component: PostPage },
    { path: `/projects/:id(\\d+)`, name: 'Project', Component: ProjectsPage },
]
```

```
{routes.map(({ path, Component }) => (          
   <Route key={path} exact path={path}>
       {({ match }) => <Component data={dataObject} imagepath={imagePath} in={match != null} />}
</Route>
))}

{subRoutes.map(({ path, Component }) => (
  <Route key={path} exact path={path}>
    {({ match }) => <Component data={dataObject} imagepath={imagePath} in={match != null} />}
</Route>
))}
```